# Apns php error "Failed to connect to APNS: 110 Connection timed out."

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I have done apns code for php and objective c from this [Apns code](http://www.easyapns.com/)

and setup certificate from [this link](https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/)

Sandbox and production apns for sending notification to ios devices is working perfectly on my server.I moved code and same certificate to client server then sending notification is not working.

I debug all php code and found that it stops at this line of code

```
private function _connectSSLSocket($development) {
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $this->apnsData[$development]['certificate']);
    $this->sslStreams[$development] = stream_socket_client($this->apnsData[$development]['ssl'], $error, $errorString, 100, (STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT), $ctx);
    if(!$this->sslStreams[$development]){
        $this->_triggerError("Failed to connect to APNS: {$error} {$errorString}.");
        unset($this->sslStreams[$development]);
        return false;
    }
    return $this->sslStreams[$development];
}
```

apns.log file shows the error "Failed to connect to APNS: 110 Connection timed out."

Not getting the mistake. Why this error am i getting and not sending notification to ios devices ? Can anyone guide me for this ?

Comment: Your client's server may be behind a firewall that blocks port 2195.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085086/apple-push-notification-service-connection-through-proxy-timed-out-with-stream same problem not resolved caused by a proxy server, the only way we found was to permits direct connections to apns

Comment: ah a problem like this will occur when you are in a shared hosting too

Comment: Thanks to all for comment. Yes i have shared hosting. Any solution for that ?

Comment: Try to looking for a VPS or an external service for push notification like http://push.io/ or http://www.pushwoosh.com/ or http://openpush.im/

Comment: Luca Machettelodicoaff Brognar is push notification will not work with shared hosting ? I can't use external service and can't move client server to vps. Is any solution with shared hosting ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stream\_socket\_client unable to connect (connection timed out)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769189/stream-socket-client-unable-to-connect-connection-timed-out)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i took vps instead of shared hosting.
Lucabro's comments helped me to solve. Thanks Lucabro.

Comment: is iphone apns php not working for shared hosting are you sure

Comment: @ReNiShAR Yes i am sure.

Comment: I also ran into this problem with a script that was on shared hosting. We told the host about the problem and they enabled port 2195 in their firewall for us - so that might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to use a cloud function like firebase to run the actual apns connection and expose an API for your other backend in the shared hosting.
This is what I used when I run in this problem.

Firebase cloud functions are convenient easy to develop and virtually free.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions

I'll post my solution to sometimes next week.