# Time out when sending iOS push Notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've been searching for weeks about my problem, but I can't find a solution. I've tried everything related to iOS push notifications service, but nothing works. Here's my problem:

When uploading my `php` file and `.pem` file to my server, I get a `timed out error` when sending the notification.

1. My production certificate is 100% working, because I test the script on my local machine and it sends the notification.
2. I'm using the right URL: `gateway.push.apple.com` and the right port `2195`
3. I know the device token changes when I'm on production.
4. My server doesn't have Firewall and it has `17.xxxx` ports opened.
5. I tested notifications in development and it worked on the server.
6. I'm using an absolute path to my certificate `/home/project/public_html/ck.pem`

So I just want to know if there's any new configuration that I have to do on my server when changing from development to production, because it worked some time ago with dev certs.

Note that notifications work on my local machine with `MAMP` and with production cert.

**EDIT**

This is the code I use to send a simple notification:

```
    <?php


    $deviceToken = 'DISTRIBUTION TOKEN';


    $passphrase = '*******';


    $message = 'Hey! It's working';



    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/home/project/public_html/ck.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

    // Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: edited post with code

Comment: simple, free, immediate and multi platform (ios, android, win) try to use this https://www.parse.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025488/apns-php-error-failed-to-connect-to-apns-110-connection-timed-out

Comment: Are you testing on iOS 8?

Comment: have you tried the same with curl?  validate it there and work through it.

Answer (score 2):

It had happened to me also, the reason turned out to be the fact that my server was blocking 2195 port .. try running this command to your server from terminal

**telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195**

you should get the following response
Trying 17.172.234.2...
Connected to gateway.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.

if you get connection timed out then your server is blocking the port 2195

Answer (score 1):

Can you try by changing the php code from

```
 $message = 'Hey! It's working';
```

to

```
 $message = "Hey! It's working";
```

are you sure that 
1.you are passing the correct deviceToken ?
2.using the production certificate in the ios app. 
3. at the time of creating the ck.pem for production you have used the public key of CSR to export pem ?